# Converted function from c# to vb.net is not working properly

Tags: c#, vb.net, function

I have this c# code that can convert dynamic sql query to simple sql query

```
    using System;
    using System.Linq;
    using System.Text.RegularExpressions;
                        
    public class Program
    {
        public static void Main()
        {
            var sql = @"
exec sp_executesql N' select Blobdata from ES00Blob  where KeyID = @KeyID AND ObjectID = @ObjectID  ',N'@KeyID nvarchar(15),@ObjectID nvarchar(13),@TypeID int',@KeyID=N'100',@ObjectID=N'ES00DBPROFILE'
    ";
            Console.WriteLine(ConvertSql(sql));
        }
    
        public static string ConvertSql(string origSql)
        {
            var re = new Regex(@"exec*\s*sp_executesql\s+N'([\s\S]*)',\s*N'(@[\s\S]*?)',\s*([\s\S]*)", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase); // 1: the sql, 2: the declare, 3: the setting
            var match = re.Match(origSql);
            if (match.Success)
            {
                var sql = match.Groups[1].Value.Replace("''", "'");
                var setting = match.Groups[3].Value + ',';
        
                var re2 = new Regex(@"@[^',]*?\s*=");
                var variables = re2.Matches(setting).Cast<Match>().Select(m => m.Value).ToArray();
                var values = re2.Split(setting).Where(s=>!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(s)).Select(m => m.Trim(',').Trim().Trim(';')).ToArray();
                for (int i = variables.Length-1; i>=0; i--)
                {
                    sql = Regex.Replace(sql, "(" + variables[i].Replace("=", "")+")", values[i], RegexOptions.Singleline | RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
                }
                return sql;
            }
        
            return @"Unknown sql query format.";
    
        }
    }
```

For example its result for the query in sql variable is the bellow

```
select Blobdata from ES00Blob  where KeyID = N'100' AND ObjectID = N'ES00DBPROFILE'
```

When i convert it to vb.net through this site https://converter.telerik.com , in order to use it in a vb.net project it is converted like bellow

```
     Imports System
        Imports System.Linq
        Imports System.Text.RegularExpressions
        
        Public Class Program
            Public Shared Sub Main()
                Dim sql = "

exec sp_executesql N' select Blobdata from ES00Blob  where KeyID = @KeyID AND ObjectID = @ObjectID  ',N'@KeyID nvarchar(15),@ObjectID nvarchar(13),@TypeID int',@KeyID=N'100',@ObjectID=N'ES00DBPROFILE'
        
        "
                Console.WriteLine(ConvertSql(sql))
            End Sub
        
            Public Shared Function ConvertSql(ByVal origSql As String) As String
                Dim re = New Regex("exec*\s*sp_executesql\s+N'([\s\S]*)',\s*N'(@[\s\S]*?)',\s*([\s\S]*)", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase)
                Dim match = re.Match(origSql)
        
                If match.Success Then
                    Dim sql = match.Groups(1).Value.Replace("''", "'")
                    Dim setting = match.Groups(3).Value & ","c
                    Dim re2 = New Regex("@[^',]*?\s*=")
                    Dim variables = re2.Matches(setting).Cast(Of Match)().[Select](Function(m) m.Value).ToArray()
                    Dim values = re2.Split(setting).Where(Function(s) Not String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(s)).[Select](Function(m) m.Trim(","c).Trim().Trim(";"c)).ToArray()
        
                    For i As Integer = variables.Length - 1 To 0
                        sql = Regex.Replace(sql, "(" & variables(i).Replace("=", "") & ")", values(i), RegexOptions.Singleline Or RegexOptions.IgnoreCase)
                    Next
        
                    Return sql
                End If
        
                Return "Unknown sql query format."
            End Function
        End Class
```

but allthough it is working it does not replace the dynamic values .

It returns this

select Blobdata from ES00Blob  where KeyID = @KeyID AND ObjectID = @ObjectID

I noticed that in the conversion the @ character before the quotes of sql variable and in the return command of the function is missing. In vb.net it wont let me use the @ character.

Any ideas what may be wrong in the conversion ?

Comment: Try a different converter; probably faster than working through and fixing yourself. I like the icsharpcode one - https://codeconverter.icsharpcode.net/

Comment: you `sql` variable is not the same string in c# and vb. The vb version does not return any regex matches. You can test it in an online regex tool.

Comment: @Anu6is it was a copy error at the first minutes of the post. I corrected it immediately. The string is the same in both.

Comment: @CaiusJard Thank you very much! My problem was solved just using the coverter you suggested ( codeconverter.icsharpcode.net ) !!!

Comment: Why even convert it?  Why not reference the C#dll from a vb.net project?

Comment: I suggest not using online converters at all. Some are better than others but they all have issues. I recommend downloading Instant VB from Tangible Software Solutions. The free version is enough for most people and it is constantly being updated to support new language features.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your `For` loop, you're missing `Step -1`.

**Change**:

```
For i As Integer = variables.Length - 1 To 0
```

**To**:

```
For i As Integer = variables.Length - 1 To 0 Step -1
```

**ConvertSql**:

```
Public Shared Function ConvertSql(ByVal origSql As String) As String
    Dim re = New Regex("exec*\s*sp_executesql\s+N'([\s\S]*)',\s*N'(@[\s\S]*?)',\s*([\s\S]*)", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase)
    Dim match = re.Match(origSql)

    If match.Success Then
        Dim sql = match.Groups(1).Value.Replace("''", "'")
        Dim setting = match.Groups(3).Value & ","c
        Dim re2 = New Regex("@[^',]*?\s*=")
        Dim variables = re2.Matches(setting).Cast(Of Match)().[Select](Function(m) m.Value).ToArray()

        Dim values = re2.Split(setting).Where(Function(s) Not String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(s)).[Select](Function(m) m.Trim(","c).Trim().Trim(";"c)).ToArray()

        For i As Integer = variables.Length - 1 To 0 Step -1
            sql = Regex.Replace(sql, "(" & variables(i).Replace("=", "") & ")", values(i), (RegexOptions.Singleline Or RegexOptions.IgnoreCase))
        Next

        Return sql
    End If

    Return "Unknown sql query format."
End Function
```